# How to define periodicity of hexagonal array?

Tags: geometry

When you have a rectangular array, it`s very intuitive how the periodicity is defined -> in x and y direction:

[image]

But what about a hexagonal array? How is the periodicity defined here?

[image]

Comment: Also just two translations in the obvious directions, see for example [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EisensteinInteger.html).

Comment: @DietrichBurde With the added complexity that there are three obvious directions to choose from.

Comment: Yes, exactly...